# How can I test failovers in Amazon Aurora DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

By "realistically," I mean that I would expect, in a real world scenario, that when a failover occurs from the primary instance to a replica, the (now ex) primary instance is unusable for whatever reason caused the failover in the first place, and it would be disposed of. That raises a few questions:

1. If an (ex) primary instance is disposed of, an existing replica is promoted to be the new primary. Does a new replica get created as well since you now have n - 1 replica instances?
2. If any of my assumptions are correct, is there a way to test this where the primary instance actually fails and is disposed of, since the "failover" function in RDS just switches it to a replica?

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure what you mean by "disposed off" in this context. In case of failures, aurora initiates failover which is a combination of a replica getting PROMOTED to a writer and the old writer getting DEMOTED to a reader. You make it sound as if Aurora would remove a faulty instance altogether. That never happens. There are some cases where if a host is deemed faulty, it would be replaced entirely. Its called a host replacement, and even in that case, you do end up having the same number of instances after recovery.

Now to answer your specific questions:

1) I presume you are referring to the case where a host replacement is initiated on a writer. In this case, for a small amount of time, you would have n-1 replicas, but eventually the new host would be provisioned for you.

2) I presume you want to do a failure test where you want to crash the instance altogether. Aurora does provide you a bunch of failure injection queries, using which you can simulate failures. I've used it to generate crashes and test failover times, I have not used it to initiate a host replacement. You may want to explore that route.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.FaultInjectionQueries.html